# Python attributeError on __del__

Tags: python, class, attributeerror, del

I have a python class object and I want to assign the value of one class variable

```
class Groupclass(Workerclass):
    """worker class"""
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        """initialize time"""
        Groupclass.count += 1
        self.membercount = 0;
        self.members = []

    def __del__(self):
        """delte a worker data"""
        Groupclass.count -= 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    group1 = Groupclass()
```

This execution result is correct, but there's an error message that says:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'count'" in <bound method Groupclass.__del__ of <__main__.Groupclass instance at 0x00BA6710>> ignored
```

Can someone tell me what me I did wrong?

Comment: Your `Workerclass` base class appears to have a `__del__` method that is trying to do something with `count`, but you didn't share that method here.

Comment: sorry I don't know that's related...

Comment: Your message is a warning only, it is not an error. **Something** in the `__del__` method tried to do something with the `count` attribute and failed.

Comment: there's actually nothing inside `__del__` except `Groupclass.count -= 1`.   So is what bothers me because I haven't done anything yet.

Comment: But that is the code that generates that error message; it is rather relevant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `__del__` method assumes that the class is still present by the time it is called.

This assumption is incorrect. `Groupclass` has already been cleared when your Python program exits and is now set to `None`.

Test if the global reference to the class still exists first:

```
def __del__(self):
    if Groupclass:
        Groupclass.count -= 1
```

or use `type()` to get the local reference:

```
def __del__(self):
    type(self).count -= 1
```

but do note that this means that the semantics for `count` change if `Groupclass` is subclassed (each subclass gets a `.count` attribute versus only `Groupclass` having a `.count` attribute).

Quoting from the `__del__` hook documentation:

> **Warning**: Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead. Also, when `__del__()` is invoked in response to a module being deleted (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals referenced by the `__del__()` method may already have been deleted or in the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting down). For this reason, `__del__()` methods should do the absolute minimum needed to maintain external invariants. Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

If you are using Python 3, two additional notes apply:

- CPython 3.3 automatically applies a [randomized hash salt](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) to the `str` keys used in a `globals` dictionary; this also affects the order in which globals are cleaned up, and it *could* be that you see the problem on only *some* of the runs.
- CPython 3.4 no longer sets globals to `None` (in most cases), as per [Safe Object Finalization](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-442); see [PEP 442](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/).

Comment: Thank you it's working now.   Now my question is if I want to `del` a `Groupclass` object, `Groupclass` object or 'Groupclass' itself must exist before the `del` will be executed so it seems the statement is somehow redundant?

Comment: @Chandler: No, when the interpreter exists, global names can be cleaned up before instances are; the `Groupclass` name has been cleaned up already. You can also use `type(self).count` instead, unless you have subclasses that do not have their own count.

Comment: still don't quite understand about this concept but thanks I'll look into this!

Comment: "Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the __del__() method is called." Does this imply that if I rename to _Groupclass, the problem is solved?

Comment: @acai: no. It means that objects bound to names with `_` at the start can count on names that do not start with `_` to be deleted later, so you can still rely on imported modules (which typically have non-private names) are still available.

Answer (score 1):

When `__del__()` method called, the Groupclass may be recovered by the garbage collection mechanism, so using Groupclass.xxx may failed. But you can access the count variable through `self.__class__.count`. Code likes below:

```
def __del__(self):
    self.__class__.count -= 1
```