# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error when trying to run chromedriver for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to run Selenium based tests on an Ubuntu based server from Jenkins but get the following cryptic errors:

**First:**

```
+ python manage.py jenkins --enable-coverage --settings=Modeling.settings.dev
......EException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b67b3ac50>> ignored
EException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b2ed10>> ignored
EEException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b4bad0>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66ad5a90>> ignored
EException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66ae3110>> ignored
EEException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66af06d0>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66af12d0>> ignored
EException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66af1ad0>> ignored
EEException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b03ad0>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b08f50>> ignored
EEEException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b08790>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b08d50>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b0bbd0>> ignored
EEException AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66a95a10>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f6b66b08550>> ignored
```

**And then a bit further down:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/GS_modelling_web_tests/workspace/modeling/Modeling/tests/BaseTest.py", line 18, in setUp
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome( ChromeDriver.path() )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 62, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

For the first error I have seen [Scrapy with selenium, webdriver failing to instantiate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674088/scrapy-with-selenium-webdriver-failing-to-instantiate) but that seems to be something else related to shutting down? And the second error seems related to shebangs according to [OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606653/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error) but I haven't managed to understand whether I can use that information. What's going on here?

Comment: I have a similar error which I have [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52297117/exec-format-error-while-trying-to-run-a-python-application-in-linux-based-os). Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

ChromeDriver executable available here is not supported on Ubuntu platform.
For Ubuntu use chromedriver for ubuntu http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_linux32.zip or http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.23/chromedriver_linux64.zip

The complete list can be found at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads