# AttributeError: 'Magic' object has no attribute 'cookie' while using python-jira

Tags: python, jira, attributeerror, python-jira

I've run into this issue while using the jira library for python. Despite setting the appropriate parameters for basic auth, I get the following:

> Exception ignored in: <bound method Magic.**del** of <magic.Magic object at 0x7f2a4e5ff128>>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/keckj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/magic.py", line 129, in **del**
> if self.cookie and magic_close:
> AttributeError: 'Magic' object has no attribute 'cookie'

Here's a quick snippet:

```
from jira import JIRA

user = 'xxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxx.com'
apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
jira_server = 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.jira.com'
options = {'server': jira_server}

jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user,apikey))

issue = jira.issue("KEY-123")
issue_summary = issue.fields.summary
issue_description = issue.fields.description
print('JIRA ISSUE SUMMARY: %s' %str(issue_summary))
print('JIRA ISSUE DESCRIPTION: %s' %str(issue_description))
```

I've dug in a few directions via Google but been coming up short:

- https://github.com/Linaro/jipdate/issues/30
- https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/issues/47
- [Python attributeError on __del__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058730/python-attributeerror-on-del)
- https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/pull/222

Answer (score 13):

I found the answer buried at bottom of https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/pull/222:

> Apparently python-jira expects the filemagic python package, which takes a flags parameter, but for some reason our environment had your python-magic package, which expects different parameters.

Direct link: https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/pull/222#issuecomment-675354824

To resolve this, I ran `pip install filemagic` and voila, no further exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "pip install filemagic", but it didn't fix it. It looks like the python-magic module is still installed, and getting picked up. However, another library I use, thehive4py lists python-magic as a dependancy.

You have to also uninstall python-magic at both the system (sudo) and user level. "pip3 uninstall python-magic". But, as stated before, it might/will break other libraries.

Why would someone think it is a good idea to have pip modules with conflicting names? Then, have one throw an error due to poor programing practices. jeesh.